# pjax alternatives for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, pjax

Finding the interesting railscast on pjax
http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax

I would like to ask for some advice if there are other tools / gems that can update a portion of a page? I have tried to build something similar very basic ajax with an div that replaced content, wich was not ideal.

Pjax looks promising but are there other options out there that anyone would recommend over pjax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of interest with pjax is not to update arbitrary content without reloading the page. jQuery does that (as do most JavaScript frameworks). The idea is to combine this "basic" feature with the [HTML 5 push state API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to improve the users experience (for example use of the browsers next/previous buttons whenever they perform an Ajax call). Unfortunately, the HTML5 history API is not implemented the same way by all browsers. To get the push state / history API part working consistently you may also have a look to [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js) that provides fallback features for HTML 4 browsers.

Anyhow, jQuery and tons of plugins (Ajax Form, jQuery tabs, etc.) allow you to update some page content without reloading the whole page.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I try PJAX for now and see how things go performance wise